# Append string to Array in non-mutative way in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

I have function that returns a string or an array of strings depending on some rules defined inside.

So we want to basically take that String/Array and basically make sure that we end up with an array of strings with an additional string 'X' added as last item to that array.

Comment: I don't quite understand the question. Could you possibly give an example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`concat` is a very useful array method for that purpose, since it both accepts an array as argument or a non-array. Either way it will concatenate those/that value(s) to the array on which it is called, and return the result.

In addition, `concat` accepts more than one argument, so you can at the same time add some other value, like "X":

```js
function f(b) {
  if (b) return ["a", "b"];
  else return "a";
}

// call f twice, the first time it returns "a", the second time ["a", "b"] 
for (let b = 0; b < 2; b++) { 
    let res = [].concat(f(b), "X");
    console.log(res);
}
```

Comment: Great solution. Tested and works like a dream. Thanks mate. @trincot

Comment: Question: Can we also account for 'undefined'? 
So we can have string/array/undefined but we always need an array back of at least the appended string. @trincot

Comment: Can you given an example? I mean if you replace `"a"` in this code with `undefined`, it will just put `undefined` in the resulting array. Not sure what you are after...

Answer (score 0):

```
function append(vec, word){
    if (typeof(vec)==="string"){
        vec = [vec]
    }
    return vec.concat(word)
}
a = "foo"
b = ["foo","bar"]
append(a,"xyz") //-> [ 'foo', 'xyz' ]
append(b,"xyz") //-> [ 'foo', 'bar', 'xyz' ]
```

Answer (score 0):

When you're dealing with a variable that may or may not already be an array, the `.flat()` method comes in handy, so you can wrap it in an array and then make sure the array is only one level deep.

This is how I would achieve this, and there are two different ways you could write up this function, so I'll include both below:

```js
const stringExample = "test";
const arrayExample = ["1", "2", "3"];

const xStrings1 = strings => [...[strings].flat(), "X"]; // option 1
const xStrings2 = strings => [strings, "X"].flat(Infinity); // option 2

console.log(xStrings1(stringExample)); // -> ["test", "X"]
console.log(xStrings2(stringExample)); // -> ["test", "X"]

console.log(xStrings1(arrayExample)); // -> ["1", "2", "3", "X"]
console.log(xStrings2(arrayExample)); // -> ["1", "2", "3", "X"]
```

I've benchmark-tested both functions with both examples of sample data, and they are nearly identical in performance for both types. Neither is conclusively faster than the other, so it's up to you which you would prefer to use.

Comment: Thank you for this solution mate.

Comment: Sure thing @RizwanAhmed. I hope this helped 